# How can I securely call a web service (.asmx) which is used for internal purposes from Jquery in a ASP.Net Web Forms application?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, security, asmx

I have a system which uses Jquery AJAX calls to an .ASMX web service for INTERNAL and STATELESS use.
For example, after pressing a button, a Jquery call is launched to insert a new user).

Now, the problem is, that the Jquery AJAX call is dynamically inserted by the user. The user can decide what code of Javascript to put, so he may call a AddUser() function in the web service, or do something else. Then, that piece of code is inserted dynamically and the button will add all the Javascript that the user wrote into the HTML content.

In the case the user decides to call the Jquery and specifically adds a code to call the AddUser() function in the WS, how can I do it securely? How can I assure that this AJAX request is coming from the same domain?
I understand that every HTTP Request header can be manipulated, so how can I assure that the AJAX call is coming from the same site?
I remind you, the purpose of that web service is for internal uses of the system - so I don't want that an external user will read the JS code and copy it an add users as much as he wants!

I don't want to use tokens or identification. It is a stateless request and I just want to add a user but to have control of who is making the call.

I will be happy to get any suggestion. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you can't. You either add some kind of authentication (if you have one on the site you may use the same authentication) or render a token on the page which is sent with the AJAX request. Of course in both cases you add some form of state but in my opinion the requirement to originate the request from the same site is a requirement to track state.

Comment: How would you act in this scenario?:

I have a website which does INTERNAL and STATELESS actions using Ajax calls, (Something like PageMethods or WebMethods in an asmx file), which are part of the website and do not depend on ANY user state. nor authentication.

The function is crucial for the internal use of the site, but because it is stateless and written in Javascript, it can be visible and usable for anyone who wants to do any harm, simply viewing the source of the page.

My question is: How could I secure this action, without using any state at all?

Comment: And I must say that I CANNOT deny\block any access to external users/domains in the Web.Config because I have other web services that use tokens on the same site.

Comment: How do you block access to the actual application that needs to do these calls?

Comment: I don't. I don't know the who source of the request is. I only know that only the same domain can make those request.

Comment: I am confused. As far as I understand you have an app (html + js) that users use internally to access part of the service that is also accessible from the Internet. Is that correct? If so how do you protect the original app so that someone from the outside cannot access it.

Comment: Yes this is correct. And that is exactly what I was asking. How can I secure my app so that the Javascript Ajax calls to the server (that update or insert things into the database) are not called from outside my app. All this, without managing any sort of state or authenticated session

Comment: How do you secure access to the original app (not the API)? Basically how do you define "internal"? How do you know that this app is accessed only internally?

Comment: "internal" is what I want it to be. It doesn't mean it really is internal, because if I just create a simple AJAX function that calls a WebMethod in an asmx file that changes the database, I have no idea if the call to that function was internal or external.
That is my whole problem. I would like to know that only MY SITE can call that ASMX function without allowing any external use of that same AJAX code

Comment: I don't think this is possible without tokens or authentication. You can make your website a proxy where the client calls your server and your server calls the asmx Web Method and hardcode the token in it but I guess you don't want to do that.